# Reading numbers from memory and outputting the value

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

I have a code that stores the numbers 0 to 9 inside the memory and loads them in ZL and ZH then moves the result to Register 17 and outputs it.

Everything works great when i put the numbers inside `table` from 0 to 9 in binary,

but when i want to count down and i switch the numbers to `9 to 0` inside `table` i get `Invalid opcode 0xF998 at PC=0x0006` error, if i switch back to `0 to 9` it works again, I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the first values being already stored `0 to 9` so there is no place for the second one `9 to 0`, but i couldn't find a way to fix.

This is the working code that counts from 0 to 9.

```
.org 0x00

LDI R17, 0xFF
OUT DDRD, R17 //Define PORT D output

table: //save in memory
.DB 0b11000000, 0b11111001, 0b10100100, 0b10110000, 0b10011001, 0b10010010, 0b10000010,0b11111000, 0b10000000, 0b10011000, 0

main:
CALL loadFromMemory
RJMP main

loadFromMemory: //load from memory into Z
LDI ZH, HIGH(2*table)
LDI ZL, LOW(2*table)

loop:
LPM R17, Z+ //Load from Z into R17
CPI R17, 0
BREQ end
OUT PORTD, R17  //Output R17 to PORT D
CALL delay
RJMP loop

end:
RET

delay:
LDI R19,60
delay1:
LDI R20,60
delay2:
LDI R21,60
delay3:
DEC R21
BRNE delay3
DEC R20
BRNE delay2
DEC R19
BRNE delay1
RET
```

in the none working code i just switched `table:` to

```
.DB 0b10011000, 0b10000000, 0b11111000, 0b10000010, 0b10010010, 0b10011001, 0b10110000, 0b10100100, 0b11111001, 0b11000000, 0
```

Comment: That is not MIPS. Your problem is you put your table in the middle of the code, so the cpu tries to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

After `OUT DDRD, R17` there is no jump instruction. Therefore `table` being executed as opcodes.

You need to add `rjmp main` before the `table:` or move `table:` to the end of the program